# Invoking a method of another Java Project from a Web Project deployed in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Web Project which is running on Tomcat7.
When a user uploads a pdf file I want to pass it to another Java Project which can be called by command line (not written by me but by Apache).

Since the Web Project itself is quite huge, I do not want to include the other Java Project inside the Web Project. 
Also logically it makes sense to keep the Projects separate.

This is how the flow works - User uploads a pdf file. This is passed to the Web Projects Business Layer. . After getting the details of the pdf from the "other" project I want to save it in the DB via the Web Projects DAO layer.

Can you suggest ways to call the method of another Project?

Comment: you have to make the runtime of that project (jars and dependencies) available in your WebApp, then you can use every class in it.

Comment: @Juniad: Have u got the solution for this? Actually I have the same scenario facing here. If u have the solution pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper for this command line tool and host it as service. It will be easier for your webcomponent to deal with service. Also all the exception scenario can be handled by service making it easier for your webproject

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script and call it from your webproject to invoke another project

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("script.sh");
```